# Where can I find management documentation of industry projects?

Tags: documentation

I'm required to research an industry engineering project and analyse the way the project was managed over the project life cycle.

Is there a resource where you can access real industry project's documentation involving the management of the project. such as projects plans, quality control docs, work breakdown structures, risk analysis etc?

Comment: Those data is quite vital to companies. I assume they will not share it from an economic and a legal point of view. You might succeed if you focus on public organisations like NASA. You might find data from (quite) old projects...

Comment: The Chaos Report has a lot of links and referenced material in it.

Comment: Bad idea, you should always create documentation which takes into account your specifics and then just evolutionary adjust it.
In such a way you shall avoid unnecessary details. Or format no one reads.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to find some of that information in the form of white papers [[1]](https://www.pmi.org/business-solutions/white-papers) [[2]](https://www.projectmanagement.com/white-papers/) [[3]](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=project+management+white+papers&ia=web).  However, as @Tob states in comment, the level of detail you seek is generally not released.  As an alternative, you may be able to partner with a project manager or three.  They should be able to describe and exemplify their documentation.